# Precedence of numeric types in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am totally up a tree with respect to the way `T-SQL` handles [type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) with various `numeric` types used in a [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression. Could you please explain it using the following test:

```
-- Consider the query:
SELECT
CASE
        WHEN 1=1 THEN CAST(1.555 AS numeric(16,3))
        ELSE  CEILING((1+1) * CAST(1 AS Numeric(16,2)) * CAST(1 AS int))
END AS Test
-- This returns 2 (scale = 0)
-- Now, remove the CEILING function:
SELECT
CASE
        WHEN 1=1 THEN CAST(1.555 AS numeric(16,3))
        ELSE  (1+1) * CAST(1 AS Numeric(16,2)) * CAST(1 AS int)
END AS Test
-- and it gives 1.56 (scale = 2)
-- Now replace (1+1) with 2:
SELECT
CASE
        WHEN 1=1 THEN CAST(1.555 AS numeric(16,3))
        ELSE  (2) * CAST(1 AS Numeric(16,2)) * CAST(1 AS int)
END AS Test
-- and it yields 1.555 (scale = 3)
```

It seems wrong to me because in all the three queries `numeric(16,3)` in the `1=1` branch should take precedence over the less precise result of the `ELSE` branch.

Comment: My guess is the query parser does not account for a hard coded true and evaluates both for a compatible type.  If this was select from a table all the values returned would need to be the same type.

Comment: @Blam: I know it does not account for that, and even then the resulting type should be the one with the highest precedence (as per the referenced specification of the CASE operator), which does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @Blam: What troubles me is that it does *not* take the actually executing branch into account...

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense to have a difference in behavior between your examples. That seems to be a bug. Good luck getting that fixed ;)

Comment: If you know it does not account for that then why does that trouble you?  In a real query that could be both true and false in different rows and the query needs to return one type.  It does not violate CASE as it is returning decimal.  Just decimal of differing scale / percision.  The query processor must make best guess of precision and scale.

Comment: The expression inside `CEILING` evaluates to `numeric(38,2)`, so `CEILING` evaluates to `numeric(38,0)`.  That beats the precision of `numeric(16,3)` and is what is used for the result.  Likewise in your second example the result in the else of `numeric(38,2)` is what is used.e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the second branch of the case has a different datatype in each case.

```
SELECT CAST(1.555 AS NUMERIC(16, 3))                                   AS A,
       CEILING(( 1 + 1 ) * CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(16, 2)) * CAST(1 AS INT)) AS B,--NUMERIC(38,0)
       CAST(1.555 AS NUMERIC(16, 3))                                   AS C,
       ( 1 + 1 ) * CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(16, 2)) * CAST(1 AS INT)          AS D,--NUMERIC(38,2)
       CAST(1.555 AS NUMERIC(16, 3))                                   AS E,
       ( 2 ) * CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(16, 2)) * CAST(1 AS INT)              AS F --NUMERIC(29,2)
INTO   T
```

The maximum scale for numeric is `38`

The first one has an else branch of `NUMERIC(38,0)` so that is the return type also. If the else branch evaluated to `99999999999999999999999999999999999999` then nothing else would work.

The second one has an else branch of `NUMERIC(38,2)` so again that is the final datatype for similar reasons. In order to preserve three digits for precision it would need to be `NUMERIC(38,3)` but then `999999999999999999999999999999999999.99` wouldn't fit.

The third one has an else branch of `NUMERIC(29,2)`. This is not up to the maximum 38 scale so there is room to expand a bit and preserve the scale. The final return type is `NUMERIC(30,3)`.

This does of course just move the question a bit into why the second branches all evaluate differently.

In the normal course of events the following expressions do both evaluate to `int` (check the definition of the created table)

```
SELECT ( 1 + 1 ) AS A,
       ( 2 )     AS B
INTO   T2
```

So there is no obvious reason for the differing behaviour between those two. But I suspect the literal `2` is treated as `NUMERIC(1,0)` by inspecting the actual value.

Whereas the slightly more complicated `1 + 1` expression gets treated as any unknown integer would be and as `NUMERIC(10,0)`.

You then get into the rules detailed on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(v=sql.110).aspx) for preservation of precision and scale when multiplying and dividing numerics.